# infinite sequence of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

For which natural $k$ this statement is correct:

Let $G_1 , G_2, G_3 ... $ be an infinite sequence of graphs. In each of them there are **simple paths** no longer than $k$. Then it exists $i \neq j$ such that $G_i$ is isomorphic with some subgraph of $G_j$.

I can prove this statement for $k = 1$.

Comment: Proceed by induction on k?

Comment: Do you know that the statement is false for some $k$?

Comment: @Math_QED Wow, you have found a solution already? What is it? What's the least $k$ for which the statement is false, or is it true for every $k$?

Comment: Adrian Gąsiorowski: Are you sure you've stated the problem correctly? Unless I'm missing something, the claim is false, for all $k$, even for $k=1$, Can you show your work for the case $k=1$?

Comment: I didn't find a solution. I suggested using induction if you already had proved it for k = 1. If the statement fails for some k, you should see where in your attempt at a proof. This is how mathematics is done.

Comment: @quasi look at my answer below

Comment: @Math_QED I have tried to find an example and counterexample of $G_i$s for $k = 2$, but I couldn't

Answer (score 1):

I proved it for $k=1$ like this:
Let think how graphs with $k = 1$ look like. Every graph like that consists of some "pairs" of vertices connected by single edge and some "lonely" vertices. 
If there exists $M$ such that every of $G_i$ has no more than $M$ vertices, then there exists identical graphs $G_k$ and $G_l$, because there is only finite number of nonisomorphic graphs with maximum $M$ vertices.
Suppose that for every $M$ exists some $G_i$ such that it has more than $M$ vertices. Let $G_k$ be a graph with minimum number of edges from all $G_i$s (or any of graphs with minimum number of edges, if there are more than one). Then we can take some $G_j$ such that it has more vertices than $G_k$ and at least the same number of edges as $G_k$. Remove some edges from $G_j$ until it will have the same number of edges as $G_k$. Then remove some vertices until it will have the same number of vertices as $G_k$. So $G_j$ and $G_k$ meet the requierments of the statement.

Comment: Based on your above proof, I think you need to edit the statement of the problem. I think the intended statement is this: For which nonnegative integers $k$ is the following statement true: If $G_1,G_2,G_3,...$ is an infinite sequence of finite simple graphs such that, in each graph, all paths have length at most $k$ (i.e., each graph has diameter at most $k$), then there exists a pair $G_i,G_j$ with $i \neq j$ such that $G_i$ is isomorphic with some subgraph of $G_j$.

Comment: Using my suggested edit, the statement is trivially true for the case $k=0$, and the proof you posted shows that it's also true for $k=1$. It's a nice problem, and the answer is not immediately obvious (at least not to me). I think it's true for all $k$, but I'm not sure. My suggestion: Play with the case $k=2$. And then perhaps try $k=3$. If the claim holds for both of those cases, try for a proof by induction.